# How to get the name of a subreport from a Crystal Report in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How do i get subreport name in C# ?
i have one main report and one subreport.In my C# code i need to get the subreportName.

```
rptDynamicReport rpt = new rptDynamicReport();  // CrystalReport
//i need somethig like this
string reportName = "Multiple";// Where multiple is the sub report name
```

Comment: Why is this question being closed? I'm assuming the person is referring to Crystal reports?

Comment: yes am referring to crystal reports

Comment: If you are referring to Crystal Reports than please edit your question and add the necessary information, possibly with the sample code that you already have.

Comment: @divo- that is when you ask the person to clarify their question or for more info., not just close it without trying

Comment: @TStamper: That's why I already edited the question title and the tags to include the additional info given only in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
//snip

//Where report is the parent rpt of type ReportDocument (or a subclass of ReportDocument)
foreach(ReportDocument subreport in rpt.Subreports)
{
    if(subreport.Name = "Multiple")
    {
        //Not the most elegant solution, but should work
        SubreportObject subrpt = (SubreportObject)subreport;
        subrpt.Height = 0;
    }
}
```

Per your request I have added the hiding functionality, I haven't tested this out and haven't done any hiding of subreports personally. I think that this should work. I couldn't find any "Visible" property or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks so much for ur answer..I tried..
foreach(ReportDocument subreport in rpt.subreports)
{
    if(subreport.Name = "Multiple")
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}

Comment: Nathan i have one more question for you...How to hide or make visible false subreport if subreport.Name is Multiple ?

Comment: @Girish, what do you think of this revision

Comment: Cannot convert type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' to 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject'..
I get this error

Comment: I had forgotten a portion of the foreach should be rpt.Subreports try that now